# Custom operation on existing resource

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I was the simple api-platform resource configuration to access to list of user and just one user:

```
  App\Entity\User:
    collectionOperations:
      get: ~
    itemOperations:
      get: ~
```

This config generate 2 routes:

```
/GET /api/users
/GET /api/users/{id}
```

One item of `User` that represent a user account and linked natural person:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "username": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "person": {
    "id": 0,
    "civility": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "firstName": "string",
    "language": "string",
    "fullName": "string"
  }
}
```

Then I want to update a specific field of my user account: password

```
/PUT /api/users/{id}/updatePassword
{
  "password": "string",
  "confirmPassword": "string"
}
```

My current api-platform configuration for this route is :

```
  App\Resource\DTOs\UpdatePassword:
    collectionOperations: []
    itemOperations:
      put:
        method: 'PUT'
        path: '/users/{id}/updatePassword'
        requirements:
          id: '\d+'
        swagger_context:
          tags: ['User']
          summary: Update user account password
```

```php
namespace App\Resource\DTOs;

class UpdatePassword
{
    /** @var string */
    public $password;

    /** @var string */
    public $confirmPassword;
}
```

The problem is that my DTOs don't know that it has to update a user. How to indicate that it is linked to a user resource? I tried with api-platform events but I don't know when to act.

I managed to do something that works but it's that I removed all the mechanisms of api-platform...

And more generally how to save several updates on the same resource ?

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create a listener that will handled the persist part:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/

```php
class UpdatePasswordPersistSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [['persist', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE]],
        ];
    }

    public function persist(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        $object = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if ($object instanceof UpdatePassword && $method === Request::METHOD_PUT) {
            // todo: persist

            // Set the result in response if needed
            // $event->setControllerResult($result);
        }
    }
}
```

I use something like that in a API Platform 2.2 version. Maybe you need to adapt for newer version.

Alternatively you can use a custom operation but that does not seem the best way:

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers